# How do I list or retrieve object instances from a memory generation in c#

Tags: memory-leaks

I have searched everywhere, and I haven't found a way to list which objects are not getting disposed by memory collection in a memory generation with c#.

We are having two of our .NET Core services (deployed on aks) eventually die due to too much memory consumption.  (The pods in aks evict them after about 5 GB.)
Our administrator has not succeeded trying to find a good tool that can help us identify which objects are not getting deleted through memory collection in Linux.